# How Many Parameters Should Be Passed to C++ Lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am really new to c++11, So while understanding the `lamda` expression i am full of doubt. I am not able to understand how many parameter should be passed to the `lamda` expression.

like

```
vector<int> v {4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 1, 7};
vector<int>:: iterator p = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i) 
    { 
        return i > 4; 
    });
```

here only 1 argument is passed to the `lamda` function. and what is the value i and from where its passed to `lamda`.

But in the below case 2 arguments are passed

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int& a, const int& b) -> bool
    { 
        return a > b; 
    });
```

from where these two value are passed to the lamda, Kindly explain it, please clear my doubts

Comment: Each algorithm that needs a predicate or function object specifies the requirements for it on case-by-case basis. You can look it up on cppreference. Here is `std::sort` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: what is meaning of giving -1 rating, I am telling i am new, I did a lot research still didn't get a convincing answer so came to here, without answering it if it given -ve rating then how can i  able to get the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Each algorithm of the standard library that requires one or more predicates has specific requirements for the given predicates. If you look at [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
InputIt find_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

The requirements of the unary predicate `p` are:

> `p` — unary predicate which returns ​true for the required element.
>
> The expression `p(v)` must be convertible to `bool` for every argument `v` of type (possibly `const`) `VT`, where `VT` is the value type of `InputIt`, regardless of value category, and must not modify `v`. [...]

This means that the type `UnaryPredicate` must provide a call-operator similar to (in your case):

```
bool operator()(int const&) const;
```

A lambda is simply an instance of a closure type with an overloaded call-operator whose return and argument types is deduce from the lambda. This declaration:

```
auto lambda = [](int i) { return i > 4; };
```

...is similar to the following using an anonymous type:

```
struct {
    bool operator()(int i) const { retuirn i > 4; }
} lambda;
```

And as you can see, the `operator()` of this anonymous type is valid regarding the requirement of `std::find_if`, which is why the lambda can be used here.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, But one doubt, who will provide the value of i, how its getting the value, incase of operator overload we are calling it with value

Comment: @TuhinPanda Like with simple function, the values of the parameters are given by the one that calls the function. In my example, I would do `lambda(3)` to call the lambda with `i = 3`. In your case, it's either `std::find_if` or `std::sort` that calls the lambda. You can check the [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) of `std::find_if` (second version), and you see that the predicates `p` (which is the lambda in your case) is called in the `if (p(*first))`.